# Can you embed meta data into a .NET Class?

Tags: vb.net

I want to decorate a VB.NET class with meta data to describe additional information associated with the properties of the class.  Also I need this information to be visible through reflelction.  Any suggestions?  Is this even possible for me to accomplish?  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can annotate most of C#/VB entities with attributes.
You can develop your own (by deriving from  System.Attribute) or reuse existing

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20346/c-what-are-attributes for more information.

Answer (score 3):

Use attibutes on the method or classes. They are accessible through reflection.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287992%28VS.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Attributes are the accepted way to add metadata to a class, methods, properties, etc. You can use one of the many existing attributes or easily create your own.