# What is the difference between attributes and filters in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, action-filter

Now can I please get a comparison not just a definition.

Example:

```
SomeClassAttribute (or ISomeClassAttribute)
```

VS

```
SomeClassFilter (or ISomeClassFilter)
```

I have a feeling that they can be used the same way but generally speaking "an attribute is applied" and a "filter is the functionality they produce." So I could "add an attribute to a method (or class or whatever) to apply a filter.

Answer (score 16):

> *"So I could "add an attribute to a method (or class or whatever) to
>   apply a filter."*

You've got it in that sentence right there.  **Filters** and **Attributes** are not exactly comparable concepts, they serve two different functions.

I believe **Filtering** in MVC is very well covered in this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg416513%28v=vs.98%29.aspx).

**Attributes** (at least those that apply to the filters) mark what the filter is applied to, i.e. an action method or a controller.  An example would be the `Authorize` attribute.  This attribute corresponds to an *AuthorizationFilter* that implements the `IAuthorizationFilter` interface.  Applying the `Authorize` attribute to an action method tells MVC to authorize a request targeting that action method, applying it to a controller tells MVC to authorize any request targeting an action method of the controller, or authorization can also be applied globally for all requests.  Now I said before, at least those that apply to the filters, because **Attributes** are a concept and syntax of .NET and not just MVC.  There are attributes for so many other things and are generally to provide additional information about the property, method, class, they are applied to.

Comment: Can I say a MVC filter is a special attribute?

Answer (score 6):

In most cases, the attributes are used to describe metadata about methods/classes/etc. For example, there's the Serializable attribute to indicate that a class can be serialized, TestClass attribute to mark a class as a test, and the Obsolete attribute to mark something as obsolete.  Reflection is used to extract this information by a process that wants to use them.  It's covered well in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20346/net-what-are-attributes) about attributes.

The filter attributes in MVC, such as [AuthorizeAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute(v=vs.118).aspx), conveys extra information similar to other attributes -- a  controller method or class decorated by AuthorizeAttribute indicates that authorization is required when used by MVC.  But unlike some other attributes, the filter attributes themselves contain logic to carry out the actual function -- the AuthorizeAttribute derives from **Attribute** (via FilterAttribute) and also *implements* **IAuthorizationFilter**.  When MVC finds a controller class decorated by AuthorizeAttribute, it will call AuthorizeAttribute.OnAuthorization() method in  to carry out the authorization.  Also, when you are specifying global filters, you add the attribute class itself to the filters list, which can be a little bit confusing, but that's how it works:

```
void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute());
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Attributes are a feature of .NET, MVC Filters are implemented using that feature.

For example, [System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.handleerrorattribute%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) derives from the BCL [System.Attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.attribute%28v=vs.108%29.aspx).  Filters apply behaviour via hooks into the MVC pipeline (roughly speaking).